# compile cgal-python

Tags: c++, python, macos, cgal

I tried to build cgal-python and had the following errors (just a snippet):

```
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/config.hpp:40,
             from /opt/local/include/CGAL/config.h:37,
             from /opt/local/include/CGAL/basic.h:28,
             from Kernel_module.cpp:21,
             from All_files_at_once.cpp:1:
/opt/local/include/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp:17:19: error: cstddef: No such     file or directory
```

Where are the header files of standard C library on MacOS Lion?

Comment: `cstddef` is a C++ header, not a C header.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded XCode to 4.1 and now the above errors are gone.